# edit xml file using sed or something by matching over multiple lines

Tags: python, bash, sed

I'd like to 'edit' some xml files, which may have similar sections multiple times in one file.
I need add 2 possible missing lines (i call it a pair) inside each section.. i.e. check if the 'pair' exists or not, if it does not then add them.

e.g. below is the possible missing pair lines i'd like to add in.

```
<arg>--possibleMissedKey</arg>
<arg>possibleMissedValue</arg>
```

Below file has the pair, so i do not need to add them in
but if any of the  section did miss this pair, i'd like to add the pair in to the section.. Also the number of lines in each section is not predictable.

```
    <some-tag-section-not-interesting>
        some contents not interesting to me
    </some-tag-section-not-interesting>
    <some-tag-to-look-for>
        <some stuff - a> ..... </some stuff - a>
        <arg>--possibleMissedKey</arg>
        <arg>possibleMissedValue</arg>
        <something-else-not-interesting>blahblah</something-else-not-interesting>
    </some-tag-to-look-for>
    <some-tag-to-look-for>
        <some stuff - b>....</some stuff - b>
        <arg>--possibleMissedKey</arg>
        <arg>possibleMissedValue</arg>
        <something-else-not-interesting>blahblah</something-else-not-interesting>
    </some-tag-to-look-for>
```

so i've consider a few options, but each one i've a question for it:

- the first thing came to my mind is 'sed'. I am hoping to replace the ending tag 
  `</some-tag-to-look-for>` 
  with

```
        <arg>--possibleMissedKey</arg>
        <arg>possibleMissedValue</arg>
     </some-tag-to-look-for>
```

i.e. essentially add it to the last part of the section.
but i am not aware of **whether I can 'pattern match on multiple lines' in sed**. and I have not used so called 'hold space'.
My experience with sed has been to check some string in the 'current single line'.

- Another option i was hoping to check, is to introduce a `inside_a_section_flag`, initial value is '0'. start reading the file, the moment I find a staring `<some-tag-to-look-for>`, I turn that `inside_a_section_flag` to '1',
  and once I reach the 'ending `</some-tag-to-look-for>`', I do some possible changes, and turn it back to '0'.
  so this `inside_a_section_flag`, if it is 1, means I are inside of the section.... so I need to look for the 'pair',
    if I found the pair, I turn the `inside_a_section_flag` to be 1, meaning I do not need to add the pair and can get out of the current section....
  but I am not aware of **whether sed can also work with a variable flag, i.e. do conditional replacement/change based on a variable value**.
- Should this be done by shell at all, instead should this be done by a python script instead?

Comment: I used to be fond of sed when I was younger, and it is still one of my favorite tools *for trivial tasks*. It can be used for medium complexity tasks but the sedscript soon becomes rather cryptic. Quite efficient but awful to write, read and maintain. As you want to 1. decode a xml file 2. test for the presence of a tag inside another tag 3. add a tag being sure of preserving the XML syntax, I would use Python here which has support for XML with the `xml.etree` module. Only my opinion though (hence a comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/<some-tag-to-look-for>/{:a;n;/<arg>--possibleMissedKey<\/arg>/b;/<\/some-tag-to-look-for>/!{h;ba};x;s/\S.*/<arg>--possibleMissedKey<\/arg>/p;s//<arg>--possibleMissedValue<\/arg>/p;x}' file
```

Match on a line containing `<some-tag-to-look-for>`.

Loop through the following lines.

If a line containing `<arg>--possibleMissedKey</arg>` is encountered, bail out.

Otherwise, if the current line does not match `</some-tag-to-look-for>`, make a copy and repeat.

When the end tag is found, insert the required two lines using the copied line as a template (so as to retain indentation).

Comment: this work like a charm. I have to go and learn all the sed commands in your answer and try to even learn more about the sed....

Comment: @MinnieShi see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info) for more sed info

Comment: Hi @potong, I think i understood almost everything in the above answer, after reading the sed command in the "unix in a nutshell book".. 
The **only thing** i can **not** find the answer off the book is `\S.*` part. what is this pattern in the substitute command? i understand it should follow the format `s/pattern/replacement/`... i.e. what is this `s/\S.*/<arg>--possibleMissedKey<\/arg>/` trying to find and then replace.

Comment: @Minnie The LHS of the substitution matches the first non-whitespace character to the end of the line, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions) for more info on regexp extensions.